# Problemas de algoritmos javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-metodo

estoy queriendo ordenar con logaritmo de javascript este array de objetos!

Tiene que quedar ordenado con los precios de mayor a menor;

Alguien que me diga cual es el error? gracias.

```
function ordenarRopa(ropa) {
  
 for(let i = 0 ; i < ropa.length -1 ; i ++){
    console.log(ropa[i].precio)

    let desordenado = true;
while(desordenado){
  
  desordenado = false;

    if (ropa[i].precio > ropa[i + 1].precio) {
      let aux = ropa[i].precio;
      ropa[i].precio = ropa[i + 1].precio;
      ropa[i + 1].precio = aux;
      desordenado = true;
      console.log(aux)
  }
}
}
    return ropa;
} 
 



ordenarRopa([{ nombre: 'Camiseta', precio: 12}, { nombre: 'Pantalon', precio: 2 }, { nombre: 'Saco', precio: 23 }, { nombre: 'Gorra', precio: 4 }])
```

Comment: De casualidad, ¿Cual es el error que te encuentras obteniendo?. Y también si sería posible que nos dieras el constructor del objeto Ropa para que podamos replicar el error que tienes.

Comment: El error que me da es es que no me los ordena, incluso en el return no me devuelve la lista completa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que estás ordenando los precios solo para la primera iteración del bucle `for`, es decir, después de la primera iteración del bucle `for`, los elementos ya no se ordenan por la condición del `while`. Entonces, tendrías que mover el `while` fuera del `for` para que el bucle se repita hasta que el arreglo esté completamente ordenado, ejemplo:

```js
function ordenarRopa(ropa) {
  let desordenado = true;
  while (desordenado) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ropa.length - 1; i++) {
      desordenado = false;
      if (ropa[i].precio > ropa[i + 1].precio) {
        let aux = ropa[i].precio;
        ropa[i].precio = ropa[i + 1].precio;
        ropa[i + 1].precio = aux;
        desordenado = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return ropa;
}


console.log(ordenarRopa([
  { nombre: 'Camiseta', precio: 12 },
  { nombre: 'Pantalon', precio: 2 },
  { nombre: 'Saco', precio: 23 },
  { nombre: 'Gorra', precio: 4 },
]));
```

Comment: Solo para añadir información, existen múltiples algoritmos de ordenamiento que difieren en que tan eficientes son (Por lo que hay múltiples maneras en ordenar el array de objetos de ropa). Para este caso @Cris22351.dev utilizó _Bubblesort_, pero no es la única manera c:

Answer (score 2):

Este es una manera para que ordenes de mayor a menor solo utilizando el metodo **sort**

```js
 function ordenarRopa(ropa) {
    return ropa.sort((a, b) => b.precio - a.precio);
  }

  console.log(
    ordenarRopa([
      { nombre: "Camiseta", precio: 12 },
      { nombre: "Pantalon", precio: 2 },
      { nombre: "Saco", precio: 23 },
      { nombre: "Gorra", precio: 4 }
    ])
  );
```